# Getting SASL kerberos error in Kafka when starting the kafka broker

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kerberos

I am trying to enable kerberos authentication in kafka server .Please find the configurations mention below
I am using below config for zookeeper jaas config

Getting below error during kafka startup:

```
    [2022-01-14 09:51:21,405] ERROR An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7) - UNKNOWN_SERVER)]) occurred when evaluating Zookeeper Quorum Member's  received SASL token. This may be caused by Java's being unable to resolve the Zookeeper Quorum Member's hostname correctly. You may want to try to adding '-Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1=dns,sun' to your client's JVMFLAGS environment. Zookeeper Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
    [2022-01-14 09:51:21,405] ERROR SASL authentication with Zookeeper Quorum member failed. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
    javax.security.sasl.SaslException: An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7) - UNKNOWN_SERVER)]) occurred when evaluating Zookeeper Quorum Member's  received SASL token. This may be caused by Java's being unable to resolve the Zookeeper Quorum Member's hostname correctly. You may want to try to adding '-Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1=dns,sun' to your client's JVMFLAGS environment. Zookeeper Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state. [Caused by java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7) - UNKNOWN_SERVER)]]
```

I'm trying to tackle a kerberos config as shown above .Not sure why unable to understand how it works after configuration

zookeerper config :-

```
Server{ 
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required 
    useKeyTab=True 
    keyTab="/home/apps/JioMhere/KAFKA_NEW/keytab_files/kafkast1.user.keytab" 
    storeKey=true 
    useTicketCache=false 
    principal="kafkast/10.135.128.156@ST.JIOCONNECT.COM"; 
};
```

Kafka server is as below:

```
KafkaClient{ 
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required            
    useKeyTab=True 
    keyTab="/home/apps/JioMhere/KAFKA_NEW/keytab_files/kafkast1.user.keytab" 
    storeKey=true 
    useTicketCache=false 
    principal="kafkast/10.135.128.156@ST.JIOCONNECT.COM"; 
};
```

Comment: This is zookeerper config :- Server{
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        useKeyTab=True
        keyTab="/home/apps/JioMhere/KAFKA_NEW/keytab_files/kafkast1.user.keytab"
        storeKey=true
        useTicketCache=false
        principal="kafkast/10.135.128.156@ST.JIOCONNECT.COM";
        };

Comment: jaas config for Kafka server is as below:

        KafkaClient{
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        useKeyTab=True
        keyTab="/home/apps/JioMhere/KAFKA_NEW/keytab_files/kafkast1.user.keytab"
        storeKey=true
        useTicketCache=false
        principal="kafkast/10.135.128.156@ST.JIOCONNECT.COM";
        };

Comment: Client{
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        useKeyTab=True
        keyTab="/home/apps/JioMhere/KAFKA_NEW/keytab_files/kafkast1.user.keytab"
        storeKey=true
        useTicketCache=false
        principal="kafkast/10.135.128.156@ST.JIOCONNECT.COM"
        useTicketCache=false
        renewTicket=false;
        };

Comment: Can you add the feedback from using a kinit with the principle you are trying to use?

Comment: kinit works fine but not sure how we sync  kerberos and kafka server

Comment: Can you add the output to the ticket?  I want to see if you use the domain name or the IP in the kinit.   It makes a difference.